# Owl Carousel with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, owl-carousel, angular-universal

Has anyone had luck of running owl-carousel-o with Angular Universal? I tried using `IsPlatformBrowser` to check but still it doesn't work.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="ssrtype">
  <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions" #owlCar>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of product.image">
      <ng-template class="slide" carouselSlide [width]="300" [id]="slide">
        <lib-ngx-image-zoom
          thumbImage="{{slide}}"
          fullImage="{{slide}}"
          [magnification]="1"
          [enableScrollZoom]="true"
          [enableLens]="true"
          [lensWidth]="200"
          [lensHeight]="200"
         ></lib-ngx-image-zoom>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </owl-carousel-o>  
</ng-container>
```

Have following in the ngOnInit

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  this.ssrtype = true;
}
```

There is no error in console. And following are two images to compare how it looks:

Before Angular Universal
[image]

After Angular Universal
[image]

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Doesn’t render images leaves white space and stretches page vertically

Comment: Yes, but that would be when the SSR page first renders. Then, when the client side initiate, you should have the images, no ?

Comment: @David unfortunately no the images don't get displayed

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @David there is no error in console. I have attached images to my question to show the behaviour before and after.

Comment: I don't know. Any error server side in the console that started `server.js`? What happens if you remove your `*ngIf`?

Comment: No error on build and if I don’t use ngIf same behavior

Comment: I'd be tempted to say it's not because of universal then, but without the whole code it's hard to tell. Since you only have the error with SSR (right?) you cannot reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: @David yes i understand it is hard to suggest something without the code. Let me try to get it working on stackblitz

Comment: @SaadBashir i am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Manjeshwar no :( if you find something please do share